# How do I force the native screen resolution of my display if it's not offered using fglrx driver?

Tags: ati, display, resolution, monitor, fglrx

My computer model is Dell Studio 1555: Pentium Dual Core T4300(2.1GHz,800MHz,1MB), 4096MB 800MHz DDR2 Dual Channel, 512 MB ATI Mobility RADEON HD 4570 using the ATI proprietary driver. My screen resolution is 1366x768 (16:9). This problem has been identified on Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04

I recently acquired an [LG - L203WT](http://www.itreviews.com/hardware/monitors-and-projectors/lg-l203wt/) monitor but I've found that I can't get the maximum resolution out of it - 1680x1050, which is 16:10 ratio.

The settings in Display show the maximum resolution I can achieve as 1440x900
[image]

This is also shown in AMD Catalyst Control Centre
[image]

The resolution has to be be 16:10 ratio for it to work, so choosing a 16:9 resolution doesn't work.

As I'm using the proprietary driver using xrandr wont work, so is there any other way to get the maximum resolution of 1680x1050 with the fglrx driver?

Comment: The question still applies as no solution has been given. I've supplied all the details of my computer hardware and software, so I'm not sure what else I can give

Comment: if you didn't know before, that's an autogenerated, generalized comment. Anyway, I answered your question - in the most reasonable way I could think of - but it seems like you cannot find the solution **you** want. Some things just cannot be done.

Comment: It would appear so. Thanks for giving the most correct answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely that the reason you cannot achieve this resolution on the external monitor is because the card does not support it.

Most graphics cards only support a certain number of possible resolutions and combinations, so with two monitors, the card probably cannot push the resolution you are trying to achieve. It is also possible that this is a driver related issue, as proprietary drivers normally limit the resolution options to something that is *safe* for the card.

You might be able to achieve a lower resolution that works with your monitor (such as 1400x1050), but not the maximum supported by the monitor.

Comment: I *could* achieve 1080P fine on two monitors until I upgraded to 13.04... Now I'm lucky to get a GUI at all, and when I do then its limited to 1600x1200!  Do you know of any *solution* to the problem, given that most modern graphics cards can happily drive 3x1200P monitors?

Comment: @MarkKCowan I suggest asking a separate question.